# What are the disadvantages of WPA2?

Tags: wifi, wpa2

What are the technical disadvantages with WPA2?

Comment: It's harder to get free wifi if your neighbor is using it?

Comment: Disadvantages over what? No encryption, WEP, WPA1. Also how is WPA2 configured, PSK, certificates, authentication server?

Comment: You're given the choice between an overly complicated (Enterprise) solution and a weak (personal) solution.

Answer (score 4):

You could have just tried google!

Source: [difference-between-wpa-and-wpa2](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-wpa-and-wpa2/)

> The only disadvantage of WPA2 (when comparing to WPA) is in the **amount of processing power that it needs in order to protect your network.**
>   This translates to a direct need for more powerful hardware or suffer a reduction in network performance for heavily used networks. 
>   This is an issue with older access points which were designed and built prior to WPA2 and only implemented WPA2 via a firmware upgrade. 
>   Most of the more recent access points have been equipped with more capable hardware to minimize the speed degradation.

Comment: Thanks Snox - using quoted information is fine as long as it is attributed. Your update is fine on this one - please go and do the same for your other answers. I would suggest that in the longer term you don't solely post answers copy and pasted from elsewhere, though...